# How can I return a JSX react object to the webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, jsx

This function builds each jsx obkect grid and returns it.

```
function grid_builder(grid,i,j){
    // const classes = useStyles();
    return (
                <div>
                  <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                      <Paper>{grid[i][j]}</Paper>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                 </div>
                    );

}
```

I need to append to a JSX object so I can return to page.

```
export default function Table() {

  let grid = RandomGrid()
  let rows = grid.length
  let cols = grid[0].length
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) { 
        // grid_builder(grid,i,j)
        }
    }
    return(//Need to return something here);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
  const gridArray = []
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) { 
        gridArray.push(grid_builder(grid,i,j))
        }
    }
    return gridArray;
```

I’m not sure about your use case But i don’t think it’s good idea to create grid with this approach, css grids are also so powerful maybe try to solve your problem with that as they will be more performant.

Answer (score -1):

Pass just a single object to grid_builder() function. Use camelCase names like `gridBuilder` or make it a component like `GridBuilder`

```js
function gridBuilder(itemInfo){
  // const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper>{itemInfo}</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
     </div>
  );
}

export default function Table() {
  let grid = RandomGrid()
  return grid.map(gridBuilder);
}
```

Make it component

```js
  function GridBuilder(props){
      // const classes = useStyles();
      return (
        <div>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
              <Paper {...props}>{props}</Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
         </div>
      );
    }

    export default function Table() {
      let grid = RandomGrid()
      return grid.map(item => <GridBuilder {...item} />);
    }
```

Comment: I'm the one who downvoted because your example doesn't work with OP's code.

Comment: Thank you, but will this return in the grid format?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks. IMO, `array.map()` is the thing OP is looking for

Comment: I agree that `map`, passing the object, and creating a component for the items are all good practices, but in this case, it just doesn't work in the example you're providing. You'd need at least to map inside a map, like `grid.map(i => i.map(gridBuilder))`.